# Обработка одного из результата полученного масива

Tags: массивы, php

Приветствую, подскажите как можно обработать массив вида:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [news_id] => 3
            [news] => test
            [news_date] => 1376849837
        )

)
```

Чтобы получить такой же массив, но с обработанным результатом функцией `[news_date]`
Смысл в том, чтобы в массиве через функцию преобразовать дату в естественный ее вид.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
function prettify(&$item, $key)
{
    $item["news_date"] = transform($item["news_date"]);
}

array_walk($your_array, 'prettify');
```

Comment: Сама очевидность, благодарю Вас!

Comment: Рад, если помогло!